# How to setup metamask for development so that a new seed phrase can be used without compromising current seed phrase?

Tags: solidity, metamask

How can I set up a new metamask account for development so that my existing seed phrase doesn't get compromised, and I can use a new seed phrase?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new profile in your browser and setup metamask extension separately in the new profile.

More details available [here](https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015289952-How-to-Migrate-to-a-New-Seed-Phrase)